# Which is correct: "Grails" or "The Grails"?

Tags: definite-articles

Should it be

> Grails has integration with jUnit

or

> The Grails has integration with jUnit

If the correct answer is the one without the "The", then why?

P.S. (The) Grails is an open source web application framework.

Comment: I'm not clear why there are downvotes on this -- isn't the question valid?

Comment: I'm glad someone asked this.  I've heard a lot of people refer to "the Google AppEngine", whereas I think of it as just "Google AppEngine".  Seems analogous...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, as other answers note, names of software products and other proper-noun names don't take *the*.

Yet some, especially plurals, do, like *the Netherlands*, *the Internet*, and *the Web*. (To be honest, I can't think of a software product whose name takes *the*. Nonetheless,) I think it simply depends on what the common use is for any given proper noun: try to find *Grails* and *the Grails* (and *The Grails*, I suppose) in use.

Comment: A few more off the top of my head: [the Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun) and [the Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon); [the Grinch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinch); The New York Times and The Washington Post have *The* as part of their names; Daily Mirror doesn't, and yet people wouldn't say "I read it in Daily Mirror", they would say "in *the* Daily Mirror".

Answer (score 4):

"Grails has integration with jUnit"

"Grails" is a proper name.  So the article is dropped.

Example:

"George has a lollipop."

NOT

"The George has a lollipop."

Answer (score 2):

We usually do not use *the* in front of software names. Nobody says *the Windows*, *the Perl* or *the Python*. However, in a sentence like

> The Windows computer is still working,

the article really refers to *the computer*.

Comment: As a general rule, proper nouns are not preceded from the definite article; it's not limited to software nouns.