# Why does "The Punisher" get an article in his name and "Spiderman" doesn't?

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns

Why not

> Punisher vs. The Spider-man

?

Is the word "the" used however we feel like? Could I call them "Punisher" and "The Spider-man"?

Comment: @Kosmonaut: This one? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9993/grails-or-the-grails

Comment: @Billy ONeal: No, I just realized it is a [question from ask.metafilter](http://ask.metafilter.com/162313/The-Domesday-Book-Or-Domesday-Book) :)

Comment: @Billy ONeal its a different question, because its different in computer slang.

Comment: Turns out @Kosmonaut was remembering the future: [Definite article before proper nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10020/), asked one day later.

Comment: False premise: it's *The Amazing Spider-man* !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Spiderman* is not an ordinary word while *punisher* is. People will know that a *punisher* is someone who punishes, but what in the world is a *spiderman*? The use of *the* with *punisher* then suggests that in the movie a particular character is being referred to, while *Spiderman* needs no such addition. In the same way we say *Catwoman* and *The Joker*.

However, *Storm* is not called *The Storm* because she is not really a storm, *Superman* is not called *The Superman* because he is not really a superman, and *Cyclops* is not called *The Cyclops* because he is not really cyclops. In contrast, *The Punisher* really is a punisher and *The Joker* really is a joker, in the ordinary sense of the words *punisher* and *joker*, much more so than *Storm*, *Superman* and *Cyclops*.

Comment: [The Edge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Edge) from U2 is not really an edge.

Comment: These capitalized articles are completely [bogofunctional](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/84288/2085).  Disavow them.

Answer (score 15):

**Short answer:**

The reason "The Punisher" is written that way is because *the* is **part of the name**.  The reason *Spider-Man* is written without *the* is because it is not part of the name.

**Longer explanation:**

Proper nouns are special, because a proper noun is a reference that points a single entity.

Articles (*a*, *the*) in English are most commonly used in discourse to help disambiguate nouns.  When I say "a duck", it usually means that I am not referring to any duck in particular.  When I say "the duck", it usually means that I am talking about a duck that is known to me and to the listener(s), either because I have talked about it before, or because there is only one around.

Since proper nouns already point to a single unique entity, there is no need to add an article.

However, if *the* or *a* is **part of the name**, then it should always be used with the name, and never change between *a* and *the* based on context.  Thus, I always say "[A Clockwork Orange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Clockwork_Orange)" to refer to the book, and I always say "[The Edge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Edge)" to refer to the musician.  Those articles are not part of the discourse information, they are simply part of the name.

So, "The Punisher" is always "The Punisher" and "Spider-Man" is always "Spider-Man".

---

(There are certain exceptions to this, but they are very special cases.  For example, there is the company called *Wal-Mart*, which should not take any article, unless you aren't talking about the company as a whole — if you are just talking about one of the stores, you could say "I'm going to the Wal-Mart" or "I'm looking for a Wal-Mart in town".)