# Definite article before schools, colleges, and universities

Tags: definite-articles

Is *the* always used before the name of a school, college, or university?

Comment: Then there's **Queens' College, Cambridge** (no article, apostrophe after s) vs **The Queen's College, Oxford** (article, apostrophe before s)

Answer (score 23):

My personal rule of thumb would be that if the school name includes an "of", use "the": The University of Minnesota, The College of St. Catherine, The Massachusetts Institute of Technology, etc.  (And when abbreviating one of these names, use "the" only if the "of" is present in the abbreviation: "I attend the University of California at San Diego" → "I attend UCSD"; but "I attend the University of Minnesota" → "I attend the U of M".)

But if the school name does not include an "of", and especially if its name consists of a proper noun prepended to a school type, do not use "the":  Carleton College, South Dakota State University, Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, etc.

(Naturally, as pointed out by Shaun in his answer, there will be exceptions.)

Comment: Ohio State (which alums inist needs a "The" in front of it) breaks this rule. I think it's their way of tweaking the folks over at Ohio University.

Answer (score 13):

Not necessarily.

I have come across several colleges/universities/schools (some starting with proper nouns and some not),not preceded by "The".

Some examples below:

Singapore(Asia):

- National University of Singapore
- Singapore Management University SIM
- Nanyang Technological University
  and many more

UK:

- King's College London (KCL)
- University of Strathclyde, Glasgow UK
- Courtauld Institute of Art  Goldsmiths, University of London (GUL)
- Heythrop College (HEY)
- Institute of Cancer Research (ICR)
- Institute of Education (IoE)

India(Asia):

- All India Institute of Medical Sciences New Delhi, India
- Indian Institute of Technology
  and many more.

There are perhaps more examples across the world as well.

Comment: University of Technology, Sydney.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, when saying the school's full name. However abbreviations exclude the "the."

> He goes to ***The** University of Illinois*
>
> He goes to *U of I*
>
> He goes to *Illinois*

Comment: It is common to refer to the University of Washington as "the UW" when abbreviated: see https://www.seattletimes.com/seattle-news/education/two-uw-students-one-black-one-white-offer-hope-in-their-personal-fight-for-equality/

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**: Yes.

**Long answer**:

I did a little research on this and the results actually surprised me.

Intuitively, I expected this to follow the same rule as most businesses: you would use *the* before the name of a university, such as *The University of North Florida*, except if the first word was the name of a person or geographic place. However:

- [The Johns Hopkins University](http://webapps.jhu.edu/jhuniverse/information_about_hopkins/) is the accepted formal name for that university, even though it is named after a person.
- [The Florida State University](http://www.fsu.edu/about/), which I expected to be called *Florida State University*, is labeled with the definitive article before its name in the logo.

Comment: it's the Johns Hopkins University, actually. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johns_Hopkins

Comment: @Hellion Actually it's named after a single person whose first name actually was "Johns."  His first name was his grandmother's last name.

Answer (score 4):

We used to get snotty memos saying that it was "The University of Cambridge" not "Cambridge University" whenever we published anything.

Don't think anybody ever cared - other than those employed in the snotty memo office.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "The" in front of schools and universities makes about as much logical sense in English as "the" does in the rest of the language...pretty much none at all. You just have to memorize it.

For instance, most state universities in the USA don't use "The" in the title, but a few do. For example, we have Oregon State University, Oklahoma State Univeristy, and **The** Ohio State Univeristy. You could try Hellion's rule, and put "The" in there if there's also an "of", but doubtless there's an exception to that waiting to bite you too.

The safest thing is to just call it what everyone else calls it. If you're unsure, hit its website.

Comment: My uncle attended The Slade, whose website appears:  Slade School of Fine Art ...  
At the Slade School of Fine Art we ...