# Should I use a "the" in front of this proper noun?

Tags: definite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Definite article before proper nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10020/definite-article-before-proper-nouns)

Do I always have to put definite article "THE" in front of the name of university? For example, 
Kiev National University
**OR**
*THE* Kiev National University?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don’t need *the* there. The university’s own [about page](http://www.univ.kiev.ua/en/geninf/about/) (the English version) does not use it.

Arguably *the* is required if you are referring to [The Ohio State University](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/003548.html), but that is a rather bizarre special case.

Comment: Is this the only university which needs an article in front of it? :)

Comment: What's if I say: "my friend studies at Kiev National University"? Does it sound all right?

Comment: @Valentia Yes, “The” OSU is the only university I know of that needs an article. It’s a weird quirk. **Update:** Actually the article I’ve linked to mentions three or four other (smaller) universities with this quirk. It is still very rare, though.

Comment: *What's if I say: "my friend studies at Kiev National University"?* That sounds fine. In fact it sounds quite a bit better than “My friend studies at *the* Kiev National University”.