# Using "the" with name of research center

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns, acronyms

The name of our research center is Southeastern Transportation Center, STC is the acronym, of course. In writing, I use STC, not 'the STC' but our director says 'the' is needed so that it reads well. For example, I write: *STC supports graduate education.*; director says it should be *The STC supports graduate education.*

Ruling?

Comment: Your director is your style manual. Do as your director says. I agree with your director, but that's irrelevant. When the style manual says "Write it this way!", then you listen up and write it that way. There's no point in arguing. **The style manual is always right!**

Comment: Related: [Using the definite article with acronyms and initialisms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30596/using-the-definite-article-with-acronyms-and-initialisms), [Definite article before schools, colleges, and universities](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10020/definite-article-before-schools-colleges-and-universities), and the many questions linked from these.

Comment: I'd go with whatever the boss says, unless the next case you want to be wondering about is whether "the Unemployment Office" is properly abbreviated "UO" or "the UO".

Answer (score 1):

It is neither incorrect that The National Aeronautics and Space Administration is called "NASA" for short, nor that The Central Intelligence Agency is called "The CIA".

You've got two guides to picking which to use; the choices made by the organisation itself, and the style guide of whoever you are writing for. In your case, these are the same thing.