# After I abbreviate do I need to use "the" before?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms

After I use an acronym or abbreviation should I continue using "the" in front of it? I'm assumption is no. Example:

"...at the International Association of Fire Chiefs (IAFC) Headquarters in Chantilly, VA."

Then later:

"For a number of years, IAFC has convened a round-table..."

Comment: It varies by *specific* initialism. For example, the article is always included before **IOC** (the International Olympic Committee), but not before **ESA** ([the European Space Agency](https://www.google.com/search?q=ESA+initialism&oq=ESA+initialism&aqs=chrome..69i57.5366j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) - or **NASA**, come to that..

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you would use *the* in the second example:

> For a number of years, the IAFC has convened a roundtable ...

The StackExchange question "[Using the definite article with acronyms and initialisms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30596/using-the-definite-article-with-acronyms-and-initialisms)" draws a distinction between acronyms (which are pronounced and usually don't take articles) and initialisms (which are not pronounced and generally take articles). *IAFC* is an initialism that is spelled out, and so the above advice suggests that one would use *the* with it. (I almost considered this a duplicate question for that reason.)

However, how the group refers to itself may vary, because exceptions to these rules exist and context is an interfering factor. (See ESA.) A look at [the IAFC website](https://www.iafc.org/about-iafc) highlights the contextual factors involved in using an article:

1. "About *IAFC*." A navigational menu item omits the article
2. "*The IAFC Strategic Direction* is a dynamic document serving as the foundation for the development and implementation of *IAFC programs and services*." Both usages depend on the noun phrase being modified by IAFC: "The ... Direction" requires the article because it refers to a specific, definite entity, but "programs and services" does not. This corresponds to your first example: "The ... Headquarters."
3. "Since 1873, the IAFC has provided a forum for fire and emergency service leaders ..." Used alone and as a noun, *IAFC* takes *the*. This corresponds to your second example.

In short, check body text on a website, consider whether the examples you are looking at use the abbreviation or initialism as a noun or adjective, and then adapt your  writing style accordingly.