# When should we use "the" before the name of a university or institute?

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns

Should I write "at Higher Institute for Applied Sciences and Technology (HIAST)" or "at the Higher Institute for Applied Sciences and Technology (HIAST)", and should I write "HIAST" or "the HIAST" in the rest of the text?

Also, what about "Syrian Virtual University (SVU)" and "SVU"?

P.S. I found different opinions in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10020/definite-article-before-schools-colleges-and-universities), so I want an answer to my specific question.

Comment: It’s conventional to drop the “the” when you use an acronym. It lightens the text, and makes it easier to say things like: He went to Yale and UCLA. His sister started at UConn but finished at Syracuse.

Comment: Thank you @GlobalCharm, and what about the full name?

Comment: For the full name it varies. Most educated Americans would include the “the” in “the University of Chicago” when speaking of the university in isolation. However, a very long title can get shortened in multiple ways. For example, The University of Chicago Booth School of Business refers to itself as Chicago Booth. Somewhere between these two extremes are easier-to-say forms where the “the” might go missing, especially in casual speech. It would be unusual to see this in formal writing, however.